# How long does it take for a transaction made from the CLI?

Tags: transactions

I did the transaction below

./tezos-client transfer 1 from "origin" to "recipient"

but it took 30 minutes to show on the blockchain.  Is that because it requires 30 confirmations?

How can I make the transaction speed faster?

Thanks!

Comment: Sorry, I found out there was a slight bug and many nodes were running behind, problem is fixed now.

Answer (score 1):

Tezos has a block time of 1 minute. This means that under ideal network conditions a new block will be created every minute. If you submit a valid transaction with appropriate fees to the network by any means, it will be processed in the next block.

In the case of using the CLI and your own node to submit a transaction, it is possible that your node is out of sync and not properly relaying the transaction to the network.

Once you submit your transaction, check with a block explorer to see if the network is moving forward with new blocks. If the blocks are being created and your transaction is not being included then the problem is either your node or in the format/fee of your transaction.

You can not speed up a transaction unless the blocks were full and your transaction was being delayed because it needed to compete with other transactions by raising the fee you are willing to pay.